# How to mount a partition for all users automatically using gui

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus

[image: using this] i mounted the partition , but i cant "cut" or paste or delete (write) to the partition in nautilus , but it works if i check that "user session defaults" but that makes it not accessable to other user, if i  login as other user , i have to unmount and mount again to be able to use it ..help.. i dont wanna mess up with my files , so please tell me a safe and reliable way

Comment: "man it is too much now , fk linux gonna go back to windows10"  Well then you do not need an answer... fine by me but there is no need to rant if you do. Just do that and keep it to yourself.

Comment: @Rinzwind naa , bro tell me , i am not going back from here , i am just a bit annoyed cause , i am new here and tryna learn , YELP!

Comment: If you're new, read a book from cover-to-cover or take a course and learn Linux properly.  If you're already annoyed now, you aren't ready for what's ahead of you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux works with permissions. Permissions for a user, for a group and for others.

If you want a mount accessible for more users than your admin user put them all in the same group and mount the partition with read and write permissions for that group.

The options you need behind "noauto" are

```
noauto,rw,gid=xxx
```

where xxx is the id of the group.

Create a group (one time)...

```
groupadd {group}
```

Add users to a group (once per user) ...

```
usermod -a -G {group} {user}
```

Show id of a group (one time) ...

```
id -g {group}
```

and use that id to replace the "xxx" in the mount command.